# Clarification about Python imports

Tags: python, python-import

What's the difference between `from foo import bar`and `import foo.bar as bar`?

Is there any difference as far as Python namespaces and scope are concerned? If you want to use something from `bar` (say a function called `whatever`), you'd call it as `bar.whatever()` using either approach.

I see both styles of imports in a code base I'm working with and was wondering what differences they entail, if any, and what would be considered the more "Pythonic" approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference, both for when there is a `bar` module or package inside the `foo` package, and if `bar` is *not a module at all*.

Considered the following `foo` package:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
```

If the `__init__.py` file defines a global name `bar` *too*, then the first example will import *that object*. The second example will import the `bar.py` module.

However, once the `foo.bar` module has been imported, the Python import machinery will set the name `bar` in the `foo` package, replacing any pre-existing `bar` global in `__init__.py`:

```
$ ls -1 foo/
__init__.py
bar.py
$ cat foo/__init__.py
bar = 'from the foo package'
$ cat foo/bar.py
baz = 'from the foo.bar module'
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Aug  3 2016, 18:12:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar
'from the foo package'
>>> import foo.bar as bar
>>> bar
<module 'foo.bar' from 'foo/bar.pyc'>
>>> bar.baz
'from the foo.bar module'
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar
<module 'foo.bar' from 'foo/bar.pyc'>
```

The other case is where there is *no* `bar.py` submodule. `foo` could either be a package, or a simple module. In that case `from foo import bar` will always look for an object in the `foo` module, and `import foo.bar as bar` will always fail:

```
$ cat foo.py
bar = 'from the foo module'
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Aug  3 2016, 18:12:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
>>> foo.bar
'from the foo module'
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar
'from the foo module'
>>> import foo.bar as bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bar
```

Note that in all cases where the import succeeds, you end up with a global name `bar` bound to *something*, either an object from a module, or a module object.

Answer (score 4):

When bar is not a module, there is a huge difference:

```
# foo.py
bar = object()
```

Here `from foo import bar` would be normal in python, but `import foo.bar as bar` would raise an `ImportError: No module named bar`.

Usually we only use the "as" construct to alias a name: either for adding some context to the name to improve readability, or to avoid a clash with another name.